# Chrome extension says "Read your browsing history" even thought it doesn't

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension that injects CSS styles into web pages. Because of this I need the "tabs" permission (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs, https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-insertCSS). The problem is when I upload the extension it says I am able to read the users web history. I understand that it *could* but all I want to be able to do is insert CSS into a certain web page! Does anyone know what I could do to fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure you need the `tabs` permission? The documentation says **However, the "tabs" permission is required in order to populate the url, pendingUrl, title, and favIconUrl properties of Tab.** You're not doing any of those.

Comment: I think I do need it. If I take out that permission the extension stops working. Are their any other options that I could use?

Comment: Probably not -- permissions and APIs might not be granular enough.